# How to redirect wiki.domain.com to www.domain.com/wiki?

Tags: dns, domain-name

I had installed wiki on my server. Lets say I have a domain name `www.nikunj.com`.

So installed wiki at this location `www.nikunj.com/wiki`.

Now I am trying to achieve that when any user types `wiki.nikunj.com`, he/she will see my installed wiki on `www.nikunj.com/wiki`.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

This issue should be solved in your webserver configuration.

## I want to redirect

### Apache HTTPD Server

If you use Apache, you can create a second VirtualHost for wiki.nikunj.com, with the purpose to redirect to www.nikunj.com/wiki.

With mod_rewrite:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wiki.nikunj.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.nikunj.com/wiki/$1 [R,L]
</VirtualHost>
```

With mod_alias:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wiki.nikunj.com
    RedirectMatch ^/(.*) http://www.nikunj.com/wiki/$1
</VirtualHost>
```

### Nginx

Nginx syntax is more intuitive in this case:

```
server {
    server_name wiki.nikunj.com
    rewrite ^ http://www.nikunj.com$request_uri? permanent;
}
```

## I want to keep the URL in wiki.

### Apache

You need both mod_rewrite and mod_proxy. Then, it would be something like:

```
<VirtualHost *:80>
    ServerName wiki.nikunj.com
    RewriteEngine on
    RewriteRule ^/(.*) http://www.nikunj.com/wiki/$1 [R,L,P]
</VirtualHost>
```

### Nginx

```
server {
    server_name wiki.nikunj.com
    proxy_pass http://www.nikunj.com/wiki;
}
```

### What about short URLs?

You can use short URLs in this scenario.

You'll need two rules instead one, one for the articles (e.g. /view/$1), one for the other index.php links.

**Tip:** `last` in Nginx and `[L]` in Apache HTTPD means the current rule is the last executed. This will allow you to avoid the two rules are executed one after the other.

## Documentation

- Apache: [mod_rewrite documentation](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/)
- Apache: [mod_rewrite for Proxying](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/2.4/rewrite/proxy.html)
- Nginx: [HttpRewriteModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpRewriteModule)
- Nginx: [HttpProxyModule](http://wiki.nginx.org/HttpProxyModule)

Answer (score 1):

The page you need to read, assuming "mediawiki" is what you're using, is [this one](http://www.mediawiki.org/wiki/Manual:Short_URL), which describes the various choices you have available.

Comment: I am using media wiki and read that page. But on that page "URL like - wiki.example.com/Page_title" this thing is given only for Lighttpd not for Apache. <br/> Can You tell me how to write rule for apache?